# Docker-compose with Django: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm just starting with Docker and Django. I try to create example Django prodject as here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django

I made Dockerfile, requirements.txt and docker-compose.yml. But when I try to create the Django project using the docker-compose command, I have an error:

```
docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject MyProject .
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
File "compose\cli\main.py", line 64, in main
File "compose\cli\main.py", line 116, in perform_command
File "compose\cli\main.py", line 712, in run
File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1020, in run_one_off_container
File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1100, in call_docker
File "distutils\spawn.py", line 220, in find_executable
File "ntpath.py", line 85, in join
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 7: 
ordinal not in range(128)
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I try to search the same problems, but nothing helps.

Windows 10 Pro (English is not system language, if it's important).

My Docker:

```
docker --version
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.11.2, build f963d76f
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

requirements.txt:

```
Django
psycopg2
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
db:
 image: postgres
web:
 build: .
 command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
 volumes:
   - .:/code
 ports:
   - "8000:8000"
 depends_on:
   - db
```

Thank your all!

Update: ntpath.py, part with line 85, in join:

```
def join(path, *paths):
path = os.fspath(path)
if isinstance(path, bytes):
    sep = b'\\'
    seps = b'\\/'
    colon = b':'
else:
    sep = '\\'
    seps = '\\/'
    colon = ':'
try:
    if not paths:
        path[:0] + sep  #23780: Ensure compatible data type even if p is null.
    result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
    for p in map(os.fspath, paths):
        p_drive, p_path = splitdrive(p)
        if p_path and p_path[0] in seps:
            # Second path is absolute
            if p_drive or not result_drive:
                result_drive = p_drive
            result_path = p_path
            continue
        elif p_drive and p_drive != result_drive:
            if p_drive.lower() != result_drive.lower():
                # Different drives => ignore the first path entirely
                result_drive = p_drive
                result_path = p_path
                continue
            # Same drive in different case
            result_drive = p_drive
        # Second path is relative to the first
        if result_path and result_path[-1] not in seps:
            result_path = result_path + sep
        result_path = result_path + p_path
    ## add separator between UNC and non-absolute path
    if (result_path and result_path[0] not in seps and
        result_drive and result_drive[-1:] != colon):
        return result_drive + sep + result_path
    return result_drive + result_path
except (TypeError, AttributeError, BytesWarning):
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
    raise
```

Comment: What is the path you are trying to make Django project in?

Comment: This could have to do with your system language. Presumably `ntpath.py` is trying to join something with an `Ã` which is breaking the build since it's not encoded properly. Not sure if that is a problem on docker-compose's side, or something on your side, but I would suggest you check around for that character (or other characters like it). Then either encode it or remove it.

Comment: In first place - C:\Users\Наталья\DoDj , then I had tried from C:\DoDj (in order to escape kyrillic), but had the same error

Comment: Taking a look at ntpath.py - I'm fairly sure it has to do with the cyrillic in your path.

Just curious - why are you at python 2.7? Do you have any specific requirements to stay on 2.x?

Comment: I have take a loot on ntpath.py and there is no kyrillic. I added ntpath.py, part with line 85, in my post.

Comment: I tried to add # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- on the top of file, no results

Comment: About Python 2, I just exercise a task for my intership, so I follow manual from https://docs.docker.com/compose/django :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set a locale that is UTF-8 aware at the top of your `Dockerfile`

```
export LANG=C.UTF-8
```